# How to trigger queries based on $variable value?

Tags: php, triggers

please excuse me if i am not stating this correctly or using correct terminology since i am new to php development.

I have a page called photos.php and i want to dos something like photos.php?type=me and photos.php?type=friends.  As you can infer, with type=me i want to show my photos and with type=friends i want to display friends' photos.  So i want to do something like:

```
if $value == $me trigger type=me query and if $value == $friends trigger query to 
display only friends' photos.
```

Comment: I hope you realize than anyone can change the browser URL to `type=me`.

Comment: yes, i am aware of that.  I will be sanitizing the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as you wrote:

```
if ($_GET['type'] == 'me') {
    $sql = 'me query';
} else if ($_GET['type'] == 'friends') {
    $sql = 'friends query';
}
```

Queries depends on your database structure.

Comment: Thanks Adrien.  I will test yours out and let you know.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work for me.  as you suggested it depends on my database structure and mine is quite big i am doing left joins and unions.  So it's a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = ($_GET['type'] == 'me') ? 'me query' : (($_GET['type'] == 'friends') ? 'friends query');
```

that should do the trick